# ACF Fields Rendered Outside of HTML Tags

Tags: php, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, storefront

I am using ACF and have set up a field for my products called `product_title`.

I am trying to display this custom field in on my product page using the WooCommerce hooks like this in my functions.php file.

```
function hom_add_product_header()
{
    $product_title  = the_field('product_title');
    ?>

    <h1><?php echo $product_title; ?></h1>

    <?php
}
add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hom_add_product_header', 5);
```

But when I look at the rendered page the `product_title` is rendered outside of empty `<h1></h1>` tags!

I have also tried output buffering like this...

```
function hom_add_product_header()
{
    # Add the start
    ob_start();

    $product_title  = the_field('product_title');
    ?>

    <h1><?php echo $product_title; ?></h1>

    <?php
    # Fetch the cache
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    # End and clear the buffer
    ob_end_clean();
    # Send data back for render
    return $data;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hom_add_product_header', 5);
```

But with this code nothing gets displayed at all!

Why is my content not being rendered inside the HTML tags?

Comment: Please read the documentation of the functions/methods you are using. `the_field` _outputs_ the field value directly, you want to use `get_field` instead, that one _returns_ the value.

Comment: Spot on, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
function hom_add_product_header()
{
    $product_title  = get_field('product_title');
    echo "<h1>" . $product_title . "</h1>"
}
```

The php script is parsed from top to bottom and each non php part is directly rendered on parsing. Since you are calling you function a few lines after the declaration the parser sees the `<h1></h1>` tags and renders them. After that the renderer gets to the function call an executes the function. The critical part is that you are breaking the php controll flow within the function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still wouldn't have worked. The problem was solved in the comment above.

Comment: Updated my post accordingly